# Spark memory leaks

Tags: apache-flex

I've been trying to track down memory leaks in our application, and keep finding myself back looking at Spark components as the culprit.

I think I've found the cause, but my understanding of Garbage Collection / mark & sweep is not too hot, so I'd like to verify my findings.

Many classes in Spark use `RichEditableText` for displaying their text properties (`ComboBox`,`TextInput`).

`RichEditableText` has a local `textContainerManager` property, and frequently calls `compose()` on this.

Here's the relevant abridged extract from `TextContainerManager`

```
// Line 282 - 292:
    static private var stringFactoryDictionary:Dictionary = new Dictionary(true);
    static private function inputManagerStringFactory(config:IConfiguration):StringTextLineFactory
    {
        var factory:StringTextLineFactory = stringFactoryDictionary[config];
        if (factory == null)
        {
            factory = new StringTextLineFactory(config);
            stringFactoryDictionary[config] = factory;
        }
        return factory;
    }
// Line 1204:
public function compose() {
    // Line 1238:
    var inputManagerFactory:TextLineFactoryBase = (_sourceState == SOURCE_STRING) ? inputManagerStringFactory(_config) : _inputManagerTextFlowFactory;
    // Line 1242:
    inputManagerFactory.swfContext = Configuration.playerEnablesArgoFeatures ? this : _swfContext;
}
```

Line 1242 is the crucial line here, as it gives the static dictionary a reference to our component.

(Note - I've checked this with the debugger to confirm which branch of the ternary gets executed.)    This would prevent the instance from ever being garbage collected.

Eg:  Static dictionary has a value with a reference to the instance -- instance cannot be GC'd.

In turn, this would prevent any other instances which have a reference to the instance of `TextContainerManager` from being GC'd also.

While this theory certainly matches what I'm seeing in our app, I can't beleive that there really is a memory leak in such a low-level spark component.

Could someone please shed some light on this?

BTW - I've opened a defect on bugs.adobe.com to track this issue, should it prove to be a genuine bug:
https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-29531

Comment: Have you diff'd TextLayoutManager between 4.1 and 4.5 to see what the changes were?

Answer (score 0):

I've heard there are several memory problems related to TLF.
That should be corrected in the Flex 4.5 SDK.

In the meantime, you could still open a ticket on http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/

Comment: Already opened one (sorry, should've mentioned this in the post!)